# Why the onProgressUpdate() of AsyncTask<> interface is never called?

Tags: android

The onProgressUpdate() is never called, can you tell me why?

```
private class LoginMe extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... arg0) {
        doSomething();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... v) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(v);
        Log.d("Dev", "Im in onProgressUpdate()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result) {
            doOne();
        } else {
            doTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to call `publishProgress` from within `doInBackground` manually.

> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on
>   the background thread immediately
>   after onPreExecute() finishes
>   executing. ... **This step can also use
>   publishProgress(Progress...) to
>   publish one or more units of progress.**
>   These values are published on the UI
>   thread, in the
>   onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html