# AsyncTask steps

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
public class HttpPostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    TextView txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://83.254.xx.xx/android/service.php");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "savedata"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", editText1.getText().toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){

        Log.i("debug", "onPreExecute");
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        Log.i("debug", "onProgressUpdate, " + progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {

        Log.i("debug", "onPostExecute");
    }
}
```

All i see in the log is the `onPreExecute`. The code in `doInBackground` works fine, and there are no exceptions. I would like to update a textview with the current status, but why doesnt all steps get called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `onPostExcute` takes a parameter that is of the same type as the return value for `doInBackground`, so the version you have is not the same method signature (you didn't actually override the method) and won't get called.  It should be `onPostExecute(Void result)`
2. `onProgressUpdate` only gets called whenever you call `publishProgress` from your background method.  If you don't call publish, no updates will fire.

Just a point of note, if you get in the habit of using the `@Override` attribute, issues like #1 will be caught by the compiler.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looks like the question was edited...I think this is because of the types you have declared for your `AsyncTask` methods.  You have

```
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
```

but the three methods are all `Void`s.  Try changing `Integer` to `Void`, i.e.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

Original answer:

An `AsyncTask` runs on a different thread than your main UI thread, which controls the UI (and hence your TextView).  You need to update the TextView on the main UI thread.  One way to do so is to send a message back to the main thread and implement a Message handler to then update the TextView.

Comment: Setting the text on a TextView works fine from this class. Are you saying that its bad practice, or that its simply not working? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: "Looks like the question was edited..." - The only thing thats been edited is the title :) And if i use `AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>` instead of `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`, im able to make use of the integer and return it to the `onPostExecute` as a result. If i havent missed something, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Hmmm...stumped here as well! For onProgressUpdate(), it might be that you need to call publishProgress(), as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224568/why-the-onprogressupdate-of-asynctask-interface-is-never-called